# vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider not working on c# file uri

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, undefined, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make an extension that needs to get the symbols of code files written in any programming language, currently, I'm testing on java and c#, I installed the java and c# extensions of Microsoft from the marketplace. The code below is the way i'm testing :

```
  let javaFileSymbols: (vscode.DocumentSymbol | vscode.SymbolInformation)[] | undefined = undefined;
  let csharpFileSymbols: (vscode.DocumentSymbol | vscode.SymbolInformation)[] | undefined = undefined;

  let javaUriExample = vscode.Uri.file("C:\\Users\\said\\Desktop\\PFE654\\Tests\\Notepad\\srcCut\\Notepad.java");
  let csharpUriExample =  vscode.Uri.file("C:\\HiveBackendVariants\\backendCardLikeFr\\Api\\v1\\AuthController.cs");
  
  //java example
  while (!javaFileSymbols) {
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand<
      (vscode.DocumentSymbol|vscode.SymbolInformation)[]
      >("vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider", javaUriExample).then(async (mySymbols) => {
        javaFileSymbols = mySymbols;
          console.log("sucess  :"  + "  " + mySymbols);
      }, (reason) => {
          console.log("error  " + reason);
      });
  }

 // C# example
  while (!csharpFileSymbols) {
      await vscode.commands.executeCommand<
          (vscode.DocumentSymbol|vscode.SymbolInformation)[]
      >("vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider", csharpUriExample).then(async (mySymbols) => {
        csharpFileSymbols = mySymbols;
          console.log("sucess  :"  + "  " + mySymbols);
      }, (reason) => {
          console.log("error  " + reason);
      });
  }
```

for the java example, it is looping several times, I don't know why the command doesn't get symbols from the first execution but it gets them after several executions,
For the c# example it creates an infinite loop

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this @MOHAMED_EL_SAID KADRI?

Comment: not really, for the java example it still looping, for the c# example i ended up by showing the document in the window using showTextDocument then closing it then calling the vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider on that URI to be able to read symbols